# How to make Flutter responsive for Web? Not working: MediaQuerys, fixed pixels, and BoxConstraints, etc

Tags: flutter, dart, responsive, flutter-web

I am coding a website with Flutter. My layout uses "blocks" of vertical content laid within a `SingleChildScrollView`. They look like rectangles of content (with images, text, buttons, etc in them), taking up the whole screen horizontally, and the whole screen vertically.

Currently, whenever I move the screen size around (drag the web window to be different sizes) the website breaks. If I move it to be really small horizontally, I cannot fit in the content I need, if I move it to be small vertically I get overflow errors (and vice versa). **This is because I am using `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/width` to layout my website.**

My rectangular blocks of "content" all have their same respective parent: `Container(width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height)` so they **completely** adjust everytime I move the window. Is there a better way to implement responsive web? Would it be better to just specify (for example) `620` pixels `height` for the `Container` and `double.infinity` for the `width`? And then somehow make everything fit inside not overflow/look weird? **Also, when I drag the bottom of the web window nothing expands/grows properly because at that same time all my "content blocks" are all resizing their height because I am technically resizing the screen.**

Finally, I've tried using `BoxConstraints`'s `minHeight`, `maxHeight`, `minWidth`, and `maxWidth`, yet they don't seem to work and **still** produce the yellow/black overflow lines when testing in a webview. Huh?

Also, how would I get a bottom scrollbar to appear horizontally once my webview window is fully dragged close horizontally and half my content is cut off, but I still would like to see it. Would this be necessary? Or would another solution not need this? I'm not sure...

**How are other people working around this and achieving this? I feel like I am doing this completely wrong. It shouldn't be this difficult.**

(Also, using `LayoutBuilder` I have 2 additional builds for mobile/tablet when the screen width reaches less than 1100px)